# Powershell Post request unexpected errors

Tags: powershell

This is my fist time doing a post request in Powershell. I have a fairly large request with a lot of variables, I am getting some errors when I execute.

Here is my formula

```
 function PostCustomerUpdate($cust){
 $phone = -join($cust.AreaCode,$cust.Phone)
 Invoke-WebRequest -Uri myAPIURL -ContentType "application/json" -Method POST -Body {
"Options": 2,
 "ModifiedCustomer": {
 "CustomerID": $cust.Id,
 "ADObjectGuid": $cust.ADGUID,
    "AppID": $cust.AppID,
    "AppCustomerID": $cust.AppCustomerID,
    "OriginatingSystemID": $cust.OriginatingSystemID,
    "OriginatingSystemDescription": $cust.OriginatingSystemDescription,
    "Action": $cust.Action,
    "Title": $cust.Title,
    "Suffix": $cust.Suffix,
    "Gender": $cust.Gender,
    "FirstName": $cust.FirstName,
    "LastName": $cust.LastName,
    "CustomerTypeDescription": $cust.CustomerTypeDescription,
    "CustomerStatusTypeExtendedDescription": $cust.CustomerStatusTypeExtendedDescription,
    "CustomerStatusTypeDescription": $cust.CustomerStatusTypeDescription,
    "CustomerStatusReasonTypeDescription": $cust.CustomerStatusReasonTypeDescription,
    "PreferredLanguage": $cust.PreferredLanguage,
    "Applications":[
         {
            "ApplicationCustomerLoginId": $cust.EmailAddress,
            "ApplicationCustomerID": $phone,
            "Action": 1,
         }
     ]
     }
   }
}
```

I get the following errors when I try to run

```
 At line:45 char:14
+     "Options": 2,
+              ~
Unexpected token ':' in expression or statement.
At line:47 char:21
+     "CustomerID": $cust.Id,
+                     ~
Unexpected token ':' in expression or statement.
At line:66 char:35
+             "ApplicationCustomerLoginId": $cust.EmailAddress,
+                                         ~
Unexpected token ':' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

I have tried pretty much everything i know and I am at a loss.

Comment: To PowerShell, JSON is just a string until sent through an interpreter or converter. Since your value begins with `{` rather than something that denotes a string, you receive an error. I would recommend using [here-string](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-use-here-strings-with-powershell/) to surround your JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create JSON bodies with PSObjects using hashtables and lists. A list in JSON can be replicated in PowerShell with `@()` and a dictionary is done with `@{}`. Finally, you can convert it with `ConvertTo-JSON` but it is not mandatory.

```
$body = [PSCustomObject] @{
    Options = 2
    ...
    ModifiedCustomer = @{
        CustomerID = $cust.Id
        ADObjectGuid = $cust.ADGUID
        AppID = $cust.AppID
        Applications = @(
            @{
                ApplicationCustomerLoginId = $cust.EmailAddress
                ApplicationCustomerID = $phone
                Action = 1
            }
        )
    }
} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3
```

In the WebRequest you use as usual.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri myAPIURL -ContentType "application/json" -Method POST -Body $body
```

Comment: So if I do a $body to see the formatting, it does seem to work. HOWEVER i am getting an error that its not supported. So i THINk the API is super finicky on the order.. it is moving it out of order. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: @Bnd10706, can you paste the error you get? Usually, the order should not be a problem with an API.

Comment: I figured it out... thank you! your solution worked for me

Answer (score 0):

To PowerShell, JSON is just a string until sent through an interpreter or converter. Since your value begins with `{` rather than something that denotes a string, you eventually receive an error when the parser doesn't know how to handle a lone `:`. `{` denotes the beginning of a  script block, which is another object type.

I would recommend using [here-string](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-use-here-strings-with-powershell/) (double quote version) to surround your JSON to preserve your line format and allow for variable interpolation.

```
function PostCustomerUpdate($cust){
    $phone = -join($cust.AreaCode,$cust.Phone)
    $json = @"
    {
    "Options": 2,
      "ModifiedCustomer": {
      "CustomerID": $cust.Id,
      "ADObjectGuid": $cust.ADGUID,
         "AppID": $cust.AppID,
         "AppCustomerID": $cust.AppCustomerID,
         "OriginatingSystemID": $cust.OriginatingSystemID,
         "OriginatingSystemDescription": $cust.OriginatingSystemDescription,
         "Action": $cust.Action,
         "Title": $cust.Title,
         "Suffix": $cust.Suffix,
         "Gender": $cust.Gender,
         "FirstName": $cust.FirstName,
         "LastName": $cust.LastName,
         "CustomerTypeDescription": $cust.CustomerTypeDescription,
         "CustomerStatusTypeExtendedDescription": $cust.CustomerStatusTypeExtendedDescription,
         "CustomerStatusTypeDescription": $cust.CustomerStatusTypeDescription,
         "CustomerStatusReasonTypeDescription": $cust.CustomerStatusReasonTypeDescription,
         "PreferredLanguage": $cust.PreferredLanguage,
         "Applications":[
              {
                 "ApplicationCustomerLoginId": $cust.EmailAddress,
                 "ApplicationCustomerID": $phone,
                 "Action": 1,
              }
          ]
          }
        }
"@
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri myAPIURL -ContentType "application/json" -Method POST -Body $json
}
```